# Create syntax filetype

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a syntax file for a new language/filetype. I followed this [tutorial](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files).

Here is my (not complete) syntax file, created in directory `~/.vim/syntax/scad.vim`:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif


"----------------------------------------------------------------
" scad Numbers
"----------------------------------------------------------------

" Regular int like number with - + or nothing in front
syn match scadNumber '\d\+'
syn match scadNumber '[-+]\d\+'

" Floating point number with decimal no E or e (+,-)
syn match scadNumber '\d\+\.\d*'
syn match scadNumber '[-+]\d\+\.\d*'


"----------------------------------------------------------------
" scad Objects
"----------------------------------------------------------------

syn keyword scadObject cube sphere square


let b:current_syntax = "scad"

hi def link scadObject      Type
hi def link scadNumber      Constant
```

I my `.vimrc` I added these two lines:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.scad set filetype=scad
au! Syntax scad source ~/.vim/syntax/scad.vim
```

But when I open a `.scad` file I there is no syntax coloration.
What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest you use the `ftdetect` method described in the article. And take a look at the relevant chapters (44-47) of [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com) ... this is a highly regarded source of information.

Comment: To clarify, I recommend that as general advice. For your question the key chapter is 44 which covers `ftdetect` and you can use it to double check what's suggested in your article.

Comment: Do not mess with `au Syntax`. Just don't. Who ever taught novices doing this sort of bs?

Comment: `au BufRead` is ugly but may actually work. `au Syntax` is FUBAR.

Comment: Thanks @BLayer!

Comment: @Phantom You're welcome. Feel free to write an answer with whatever specific steps you took to solve your issue(s).